# Use nested iter_map() with ndarrays

Tags: rust, simulation

I'm following along with some of the suggestions [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/283404/smoothed-particle-hydrodynamics-in-rust).

The one concerning this question involves transforming this:

```rust
// There's an outer loop that calls this a lot
fn calculate_density_at_point(sim_space: &SimulationSpace, i: usize) -> f32 {
    let density = sim_space.positions.iter()
        .filter(|&x| is_in_interaction_radius_and_not_self(x, sim_space.positions[i]))
        .enumerate()// exclude self
        .fold(0.0, |acc: f32, (j, _)| acc + PARTICLE_MASS_KG * smooth(sim_space.positions[i], sim_space.positions[j]));

    return density;
}
```

Into this:

```
fn calculate_density_at_point(sim_space: &SimulationSpace) -> Array1<f32> {
    sim_space.positions.map(|&position| {
        sim_space.positions.fold(0.0, |acc, x| {
            if is_in_interaction_radius_and_not_self(x, position) {
                acc + PARTICLE_MASS_KG * smooth(position, *x)
            } else {
                acc
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Great, I love it and I've changed all of my vecs into `ndarray:Array1`s which will be a godsend for performance.

Now, I'm trying to replicate this for another one of my functions which is a bit more complicated:

```rust
fn calculate_pressure_grad_term_at_point(sim_space: &SimulationSpace, pressures: &Vec<f32>, densities: &Vec<f32>, i: usize) -> Vector4<f32> {
    let pressure_grad_term: Vector4<f32> = sim_space.positions.iter()
        .filter(|&x| is_in_interaction_radius_and_not_self(x, sim_space.positions[i]))
        .enumerate()// exclude self
        .fold(Vector4::zero(), |acc: Vector4<f32>, (j, _)| {
            acc + PARTICLE_MASS_KG * (pressures[i] / (densities[i].powi(2)) + pressures[j] / (densities[j].powi(2))) * grad_smooth(sim_space.positions[i], sim_space.positions[j])
        });
    return pressure_grad_term;
}
```

For this one, I need to pass in the simulation space as well as the pressures and densities that have been calculated in previous steps. So again, I'm trying to get rid of the outer loop, and use a map and a fold to do what I want.

This is called from the main loop like this:

```
let densities = calculate_densities(&sim_data.simulation_space);
let pressures = calculate_pressures(&densities);
let pressure_grad_terms = calculate_pressure_grad_terms(&sim_data.simulation_space, &pressures, &densities);
```

Unfortunately, I'm struggling with the transformation on this one... As I'm having to reference the density and pressure values of the current particle and the one I'm comparing it against in every loop. Which means I've had to add `indexed_iter()` into my method chain. It looks like:

```
fn calculate_pressure_grad_terms(simulation_space: &SimulationSpace, densities: &Array1<f64>, pressures: &Array1<f64>) -> Array1<Vector4<f64>> {
    simulation_space.positions.indexed_iter().map(|(current_index,&current)| {
        simulation_space.positions.indexed_iter().fold(Vector4::zero(), | acc,(other_index, &other) | {
            if is_in_interaction_radius_and_not_self(current, other) {
                acc + PARTICLE_MASS_KG * (pressures[current_index] / (densities[current_index].powi(2)) + pressures[other_index] / (densities[other_index].powi(2)) * grad_smooth(current, other))
            } else {
                acc
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Now, this is giving me a mismatched type error that I'm really not sure how to address:

```rust
    = note: expected struct `ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<Vector4<f64>>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>`
               found struct `Map<IndexedIter<'_, Vector4<f64>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>, [closure@src/main.rs:144:51: 144:77]>`
```

So I'm thinking this whole process might be easier if I refactor the data to have an array of a struct holding all of these properties and I just directly operate on that, which would remove the need for any of this indexing, something like:

```rust
struct Particle {
    position: Vector3<f64>,
    velocity: Vector3<f64>,
    acceleration: Vector3<f64>,
    mass: f64,
    pressure_at_location: f64,
    density_at_location: f64
}
```

But I'm somewhat reluctant to do that just yet because, 1) the tutorial had separate arrays and I *think* that might be a requirement for OpenCL (I've not got that far yet), and 2) I want to understand what this problem is not pivot to avoid it.

So what's gone wrong here?

Comment: I think you forgot to `.collect()` the `.map()` or maybe should replace it with `.fold()`, too.

Comment: FWIW I think the iterator versions are more legible and better convey meaning. But I guess if the latter performs better that's a reason to rewrite it.

Comment: Adding `.collect()` to the `.map()` works... But why is it necessary for when I've got a `.indexed_iter()` but not when I don't?

Comment: Because `indexed_iter` returns an `T: Iterator` which have to be collected while `Array::map` returns an `Array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To operate over a bunch of arrays, you'll want to use [Zip](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.Zip.html).

Something like this, (Code typed out, not even a little tested)

```
Zip::from(&simulation_space.positions)
    .and(densities)
    .and(pressures)
    .map_collect(|current_position, current_density, current_pressure| 
       Zip::from(&simulation_space.positions)
           .and(pressures)
           .and(densities)
           .fold(Vector4::zero(), | acc, other_position, other_pressure, other_density | {
            if is_in_interaction_radius_and_not_self(current_position, other_position) {
                acc + PARTICLE_MASS_KG * (current_pressure / (current_density.powi(2)) + other_pressure / (other_density.powi(2)) * grad_smooth(current_position, other_index))
            } else {
                acc
            }
        })
```

Your `indexed_iter` code didn't work because `indexed_iter` returns an iterator. As @cafce25 noted, you need to `collect()` to convert the iterator back into an array.

Comment: You sir, are a scholar and a gent... I'll get this implemented and assuming all's good I'll come back and mark as accepted